# Can you use google-apis to connect google sheets with React app

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets, google-api

I am trying to use a google sheet as the database for my React App. From what I can tell it seems that this isn't possible unless you use something like sheet.best

Is there another way? If so is there a free way, as I tried using sheet.best but quickly ran out of free requests. I tried Steinhq but am having trouble getting that installed

originally I was following tutorials for just simple node applications, but those don't seem compatible with react

Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? 1. In your situation, will you use only one Google Spreadsheet that you are the owner of? 2. Approximately, how many users will access concurrently? 3. Do you use the access token for putting and getting values for Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: You can go directly though the google sheets api, set up a service account authorization for your app.

Comment: 1. Yes only one spreadsheet that I own 2. Only a couple users I believe 2-3 3. Yes I have set up the access token etc and I got that working with sheet.best

Comment: Linda, just to clarify this is possible with a react app? I've only seen examples that use node or express etc and when I've tried to convert that code to fit my app the api calls fail. I found a thread from google from 2019 that implied google-apis and react aren't compatible but wasn't sure if thats outdated

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed your reply. I apologize for my late reply. When you reply to a comment, when you add `@username` in the comment, the user can notice your reply. From your reply, I would like to propose using Web Apps created by Google Apps Script. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) Because I think that the Web Apps will achieve your goal. About Web Apps, my report might be useful. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script) If this was not your expected direction, I apologize.